# Why is this.value undefined/null on every lifecycle hook when using [ngModel]="true"

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, lifecycle-hook, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have a custom form control which implements ControlValueAccessor to handle `[(formControl)]="..."` and `[(ngModel)]="..."`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => FooComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class FooComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, AfterContentInit, OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('ngOnChanges', this.value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit', this.value);
  }
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ngDoCheck', this.value);
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() : void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentInit', this.value);
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() : void {
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked', this.value);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() : void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.value);
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() : void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewChecked', this.value);
  }

  /**
   * Write a new value to the element.
   */
  public writeValue(value : any) : void { // tslint:disable-line:no-any
    this._value = value;
    console.log('writeValue', this.value);
  }

  ...
```

I use this component like this:

```html
<app-foo [ngModel]="true"></app-foo>
```

I assumed the value should be defined at least in ngAfterContentInit() but it is always undefined or null. At least in the first run. Here are my console logs:

```
ngOnInit undefined
ngDoCheck undefined
writeValue null
ngAfterContentInit null
ngAfterContentChecked null
ngAfterViewInit null
ngAfterViewChecked null
---
writeValue true
ngDoCheck true
ngAfterContentChecked true
ngAfterViewChecked true
```

Why is value always undefined/null and is there a way to change that?

Comment: it's not `<app-foo [(ngModel)]="variable"></app-foo>`?

Comment: @Eliseo `[ngModel]` is one-way-binding `[(ngModel)]` is two-way-binding. Changing this has no effect to my described issue.

Comment: I think you should give a default value of empty quotes. So it would be null not Undefined.

Comment: why cant you declare 'value' variable at class level and set default value there itself. because writeValue() call only in specific circumstance. Read from official site:  'This method is called by the forms API to write to the view when programmatic changes from model to view are requested.'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) in order to make it work :

```
export class FooComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  writeValue(value) {
   this._value = value;
  }
  ...
}
```

The `writeValue` function will be executed when the input value of `ngModel` change. You will also have to implement `registerOnTouch` and `registerOnChange`.

Have a look at this [alligator.io article](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/) for a more information.

Comment: You are right, but it does not solve the described issue, that value is undefined in ngOnAfterContentInit. I think ngOnAfterContentInit should run after all properties of 
<app-foo ...> reach the FooComponent.

Comment: I added ControlValueAccessor to the Example and tried `console.log('writeValue', this.value);` in writeValue(), but in the first run, this.value is null here.

Comment: In your code you're initializing `this._value` and trying to console.log `this.value`